# Numpy: broadcast row values to channels

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

I Have a dataset, where first 48 observations are time series, and other 12 are static variables:

```
h1 h2 h3 h4 ... h48 v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 .. vn
h1 h2 h3 h4 ... h48 v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 .. vn
```

the shape of one item is `(367, 60)`.

I want to pass variables `v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 .. vn` as additional channels to time series, i.e. create array of the shape `(367, 48, 13)`. I want to do it on the fly, as fully converted dataset does not fit into my RAM.

The code I use right now is very inefficient (`items` is batch):

```
def preprocessor(items):

    items_new = np.zeros(shape=(items.shape[0], 367, 48, 13), dtype=np.float32)

    for idx_item, item in enumerate(items):

        train_data = item[:,:48]
        train_vars = item[:,48:]

        train_new = np.zeros((train_data.shape[0], train_data.shape[1],(train_vars.shape[1]+1)))
        for idx_row, row in enumerate(train_data):
            for idx_col, elem in enumerate(row):
                train_new[idx_row, idx_col, :] = np.concatenate([[elem], train_vars[idx_row]])

        items_new[idx_item] = train_new

    return items_new
```

Can I do it faster without loops?

EDIT:

Minimal reproducible example:

```
arr = np.random.randn(5,367,60)

arr2 = preprocessor(arr)

print(arr2.shape) # (5, 367, 48, 13)
```

Comment: So, is `items` a NumPy array?

Comment: @Divakar Yes, it's not a list and cannot be.

Comment: What's its shape? I ran with `items = np.random.rand(367,60)` and throwing error. A mcve would be nice - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Divakar  `Items` shape is `(batch_size, 367, 60)`. You can generate it with `np.random.randn(z,367,60)` where z is arbitrary number you want.

Comment: Got it. Makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1**

We could use broadcasted array-assignment for a vectorized solution -

```
def array_assign(items):    
    L = 48 # slice at this column ID
    N = items.shape[-1]
    out = np.empty(shape= items.shape[:2] + (L,N-L+1), dtype=np.float32)
    out[...,1:] = items[...,None,L:]
    out[...,0] = items[...,:L]
    return out
```

**Approach #2**

We could also use a broadcasted view and then concatenate -

```
def broadcast_concat(items):    
    L = 48 # slice at this column ID
    N = items.shape[-1]
    a = items[...,:L,None]
    shp_b = items.shape[:2] + (L,N-L)
    b = np.broadcast_to(items[...,None,L:],shp_b)
    out = np.concatenate((a,b),axis=-1)
    return out
```

Timings -

```
In [321]: items = np.random.rand(5,367,60)

In [322]: %timeit array_assign(items)
1000 loops, best of 3: 923 µs per loop

In [323]: %timeit broadcast_concat(items)
1000 loops, best of 3: 781 µs per loop
```

For a fair comparison, we should have let the second method use more efficient `float32` dtype as well. Let's use that dtype for setting up input data and test out again -

```
In [335]: items = np.random.rand(5,367,60).astype(np.float32)

In [336]: %timeit array_assign(items)
1000 loops, best of 3: 897 µs per loop

In [337]: %timeit broadcast_concat(items)
1000 loops, best of 3: 348 µs per loop
```

So, for most performant one for the case when the dtype conversion is needed, we could use `items = np.asarray(items, dtype=np.float32)` at the start of approach #2.

Comment: @Slowpoke See if just added Approach #2 brings about any further joy with your usecase.

Comment: Thanks, I tried second code, but looks like the bottleneck is not there right now. I am training neural network on GPU, and this is custom preprocessing layer, so it must be taken into account when Keras calculates time. The time is still 17ms/step, while one CPU core load slightly reduced from 85-86% for the first code to 80-82% for the second. I think that means that preprocessing is good and feeds new batch in time, while bottleneck is currently with GPU part of the computation. Thanks nevertheless!

Answer (score 1):

This is another solution by using repeat and concatenate.

```
a = items[:,:,:48, np.newaxis]
b = items[:,:,48:].repeat(a.shape[2], axis=1).reshape(*a.shape[:-1], -1)
return np.concatenate([a,b], axis=3)
```

Comment: I've already chosen the answer, the first one already reduced execution time of my code from 1 hour to 8 minutes, where performance is governed by other bottlenecks, but thanks nevertheless! Maybe it will be faster for more loaded pipeline than mine.

Comment: No problem! It is my exercise on numpy. I have enjoyed.